# Можно ли отключить уведомление в шторке о проигрываемом звуке в браузере на андроид?

Tags: javascript, html5, game-maker

Cделал простенькую браузерную игру на Game Maker Studio 2. Необходимо скрыть уведомление о проигрываемом звуке (одно из условий публикации игры - отсутствие уведомлений)

[image: Вот это уведомление в шторке]

Скорее всего тут дело как-то связано с JS. В нём у меня есть мизерный опыт (нашёл-скопировал-изменил) и общие знания вообще о программировании (условия, циклы, переменные, функции). Есть идея, создать JS расширение для Game Maker studio, передавать в него звуковой ресурс, который уже будет проигрываться средствами JS, без уведомлений.
Как проиграть звук без уведомления в JS? А если помимо одного звука играет ещё и фоновая музыка?
Прошу помочь.

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл решение, необходимо настроить все звуки так[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ещё при создании игры установил атрибут для фоновой музыки на "Compressed - Streamed", как советовали в официальной справке, больше так не буду делать :)